# Adding new column to dataframe based on several conditions of two other columns in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

In a dataframe, I have two columns A and B. Values within each column can be either 1 or NA.
I want to add a third column called C so that :

```
 - If A == NA AND B == NA, then C = "None"
 - If A == 1 AND B == NA, then C = "A" 
 - If A == NA AND B == 1, then C = "B"
 - if A == 1 AND B == 1, then C = "Both"
```

Comment: see `?dplyr::case_when`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just translate your conditions to `case_when` statements

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(C = case_when(is.na(A) & is.na(B) ~ "None", 
                       A == 1 & is.na(B) ~ "A",
                       B == 1 & is.na(A) ~ "B", 
                       TRUE ~ "Both"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(C = ifelse(is.na(A) & is.na(B), "None",
                   ifelse(A== 1 & is.na(B), "A",
                   ifelse(B==1 & is.na(A), "B",
                   "Both"))))
```